# how to fetch stream data from elasticsearch using socket.io?

Tags: elasticsearch, socket.io

I have used elasticsearch module of node to fetch data from elasticsearch.
fetching data using client.search().
code:

```
    var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');

var client = new elasticsearch.Client();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){

    client.search({
      index: 'myindex',
      type: 'mytype',
      size: 5,
      body: {
        query: {
          match_all : { }
        }
      }
    }).then(function (resp) {
        var hits = resp.hits.hits;
        console.log(hits);
            socket.emit("data", hits);
    }, function (err) {
        console.trace(err.message);
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", function () {
    console.log('disconnected');
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

But using this code I am not getting new data added to elasticsearch.
Please suggest me how to use Socket.io to fetch streaming data from ES?

Comment: Both would work, but this is not the kind of question that belongs on SO; it attracts too many opinionated answers and is not specific enough. Please read the guidelines before posting a question.

Comment: The main issue here seems to be getting streaming data from ES, which does sound like an SO question to me.

Comment: sorry @Blubberguy for improper question.

Comment: is there any example to fetch streaming data from elasticsearch using socket.io?

Comment: @SayyedM It's fine; I just wanted to let you know that it's better to ask once you've tried something rather than just asking what to do. The use of socket.io.js or sock.js is a question that results easily in opinionated answers because the functionality of the two is very similar.